# Substantivierung: "Mein Suchen war nicht von Erfolg gekrönt"

Tags: meaning, difference, noun

Dieser Satz steht in meinem Grammatikbuch als Beispiel für Substantivierung. Hier ist das Verb *suchen* substantiviert.

Duden aber sagt, die Substantivierung soll *die Suche* sein, und *Suchen* besteht nur als Plural. *Das Suchen* fand ich nur [in einem Artikel](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Heterozetesis).

Kann jemand mir erklären, warum *die Suche* und auch *das Suchen* bestehen, und wie sie sich unterscheiden?

Comment: Naja, der Prozess des Suchens (also das Suchen) ist im Prinzip eine Suche, sprich die Suche. Das eine ist eine Substantivierung eines Verbs und das andere ist eine bestehende Benennung einer solchen Tätigkeit. Das gleiche mit schlafen: das Schlafen tut mir gut. Oder: der Schlaf tut mir gut. Rein inhaltlich identisch, grammatikalisch nur scheinbar (wobei eine Substantivierung ebenfalls ein Nomen ist, demnach ist der Unterschied wirklich marginal)

Comment: @Alex warum schreibst du das nicht als Antwort?

Comment: weil mir das zu plump ist :) Der Unterschied ist: das eine ist eine Substantivierung, das andere nicht.

Comment: Duden ist, denke ich, tendentiell eher bekloppt.

Comment: 'Tendenziell' meintest du, oder? (Schlug ich nach im Duden)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Das passiert eigentlich mit allen Verben im Deutschen, wenn man sie substantiviert:

Verb: arbeiten
*Substantivierung:* das Arbeiten
das *Substantiv:* die Arbeit

Verb: trinken
Substantivierung: das Trinken
das Substantiv hingegen: Getränk

Die Substantivierung schiebt ja die eigentliche Tätigkeit (Verben) in den Nominativ.

„Mein Suchen war nicht von Erfolg gekrönt“
wäre ohne Substantivierung:
„Ich suchte (/habe gesucht), ohne dass ich von Erfolg gekrönt worden war“

Ich suchte / Ich habe gesucht --> Mein Suchen

Was du dort im Duden gefunden hast, ist *das Substantiv* zu dem Verb „suchen“, aber nicht die *Substantivierung*.

Comment: Sind Substantivierungen immer Neutrum, oder würde das zu einfach sein? :)

Comment: Doch in diesem Falle ist die Deutsche Sprache "einfach".
Alle Verben und Adjektive die substantiviert werden, sind Neutrum. Mir fällt spontan keine Ausnahme ein.

Comment: @pdah Diese Form des Substantivierens ist immer neutral, es gibt aber noch andere Formen, z.B. untersuchen - die Untersuchung. Zusätzlich können nicht nur Verben, sondern auch Adjektive, Partizipien. [Details hier](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalisierung#Substantivierung_im_Deutschen)

Comment: Es existiert nicht nur "das Getränk", sondern auch "das Trinken". Bspw. in "Ich habe mein (Zu-)Trinken zu Hause vergessen."

Answer (score 2):

Von jedem Infinitiv kann man das Gerund bilden mit "das". In deutschen Grammatiken hat man sich nur nicht auf einen einheitlichen Namen einigen können. Alles Mögliche wird dafür gesagt. Aus irgendeinem Grund wird Gerund vermieden, aber ich sehe nicht warum.

Comment: Das stimmt so nicht. Die deutsche Sprache kennt schlicht und einfach kein Gerundium. Als Beispiel für die englische Sprache: *inf* to feed -> *gerund* the feeding funktioniert im Deutschen nicht. Da wird nur ein substantivierter Infinitiv verwendet, um das Gleiche auszudrücken. *inf* füttern -> das Füttern. Beachte, das sich hier das Wort nicht ändert.

Comment: Für mich ist es unwichtig, ob man das Gerund mit einer Endung macht oder anders, die Funktion ist die gleiche. Andere sehen in solchen Unterschieden der Bildung grundsätzliche Verschiedenheit und es werden unterschiedliche Begriffe dafür verwendet, die eigentlich nur Verwirrung schaffen.

Comment: Du meinst also, dass ein substantivierter Infinitiv = Gerundium ist? Da kann ich nur mit Sven Regener Einspruch erheben: "Sicher gibt das böses Blut, doch Sprache ist, das wissen wir, das allerhöchste Gut und ohne Klarheit in der Sprache ist der Mensch nur ein Gartenzwerg"

Comment: Gerund ist eigentlich ein Begriff der Lateingrammatik und im Nominativ verwendet Latein einfach den Infinitiv. Erst für die anderen Fälle gibt es eine Endung. Englisch verwendet ebenfalls eine Endung, aber der Grammatikbegriff Gerund kommt nicht vom Englischen.

Comment: Ich habe mit Deutsch, Latein, Französisch und Englisch zu tun und es ist einfach unpraktisch fUr gleiche Sachen in Grammatik mehrere unterschiedliche Begriffe zu haben.

Answer (score 1):

> "Mein Suchen war nicht von Erfolg gekrönt"

ist, wie Du bereits richtig gesagt hast, die Substantivierung.

Mit dem Substantiv wäre es:

> "Meine Suche war nicht von Erfolg gekrönt"

dies ist gleichbedeutend.
Generell kann man aus allen Verben die mir gerade einfallen diese Substantivierung anwenden.

Comment: Klappt aber nicht immer so schön wie in Deinem Beispiel. Manchmal gibt es nur die Substantivierung. Beispiel: *Mein Tun war nicht von Erfolg gekrönt*. Für das Verb *tun* gibt es - außer dem substantivierten *das Tun* - meines Wissens nach kein anderes Substantiv.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Fällt Dir in der TAT kein Substantiv für "tun" ein?

Comment: Doch schon, aber "mein Tun" hat eine leicht andere Bedeutung als "meine Tat". Ich hätte schreiben sollen, kein *gleichbedeutendes* Substantiv.